# What is the difference between CloseableHttpClient and HttpClient in Apache HttpClient API?

Tags: java, apache, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm studying an application developed by our company. It uses the Apache HttpClient library. In the source code it uses the `HttpClient` class to create instances to connect to a server.

I want to learn about Apache HttpClient and I've gone trough [this set of examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html). All the examples use `CloseableHttpClient` instead of `HttpClient`. So I think `CloseableHttpClient` is an extended version of `HttpClient`. If this is the case I have two questions:

- What is the difference between these two?
- Which class is recommended to use for my new development?

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear to me: "Base implementation of HttpClient that also implements Closeable" - HttpClient is an interface; CloseableHttpClient is an abstract class, but because it implements AutoCloseable you can use it in a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: @JonSkeet That much is clear, but how important is it to close `HttpClient` instances?  If it's important, why is the `close()` method not part of the basic interface?

Comment: @Jules: I'm afraid I don't know enough about HttpClient to answer that :(

Comment: close need not be part of basic interface since underlying connection is released back to the connection manager automatically

Answer (score 126, accepted):

- The main entry point of the HttpClient API is the HttpClient interface.
- The most essential function of HttpClient is to execute HTTP methods.
- Execution of an HTTP method involves one or several HTTP request / HTTP response exchanges, usually handled internally by HttpClient.

---

- CloseableHttpClient is an abstract class which is the base implementation of HttpClient that also implements java.io.Closeable.
- Here is an example of request execution process in its simplest form:

  ```
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
  CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
  try {
      //do something
  } finally {
      response.close();
  }
  ```

---

- **HttpClient resource deallocation:** When an instance CloseableHttpClient is no longer needed and is about to go out of scope the connection manager associated with it must be shut down by calling the CloseableHttpClient#close() method.

  ```
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  try {
      //do something
  } finally {
      httpclient.close();
  }
  ```

see the [Reference](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) to learn fundamentals.

---

@Scadge
Since Java 7, Use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. It can be used both for the client and for each response

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()){

    // e.g. do this many times
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
    //do something
    }

    //do something else with httpclient here
}
```

Comment: This answer sort of begs the question. What does calling close() on an HttpClient cause to happen that wouldn't otherwise happen? Do you leak connections if you don't call close() at the appropriate times/places? Does calling close() prematurely affect your performance by causing you to reconnect when you really didn't need to?

Comment: I looked through the code in httpclient for the answer to this question.  The answer is that the close method is used to close internal state. Some of the implementations of HTTPClient(in the httpclient lib) can be configured to use persistent resources such as PooledHttpClientConnectionManager for pooled connections and without such a method you could not clean up these resources if needed.

Comment: @SugarPudi in the above example, do we need to close `httpget` also

Comment: How are we able to invoke methods on abstract class (CloseableHttpClient) here? Should we not create a concrete subclass first?

Comment: @illcar 
Please go throuth this answer to understand the concept https://stackoverflow.com/a/4321402/2830834

Comment: If you have set a connection pool it will close it ! Once close you would have to create a new instance each time ... Also see https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Comment: The main benefit, IMHO, is that the execute methods return CloseableHttpResponse instances, rather than HttpReponses. Use the try-with-resources for the execute calls to ensure that the connections are returned to the connection pool.

Comment: What about `HttpGet` object? Do we need to close it?

Comment: What if there is an exception and in that case closable response object will be null? How do we release the connection is such a scenario if I am not using try with resources? As I can not call response.close() now. Thanks

Comment: I guess the summary here is that the Apache HTTP Client developers don't know how to make a good API. A good API would decide whether cleaning up resources is important or not. If it were important, then HttpClient would extend Closeable. If it were not important, then HttpClient would not extend Closeable and CloseableHttpClient would not exist. I assume they are just unable to decide which direction to go in.

Answer (score 34):

Had the same question.  The other answers don't seem to address why close() is really necessary?  Also, Op seemed to be struggling to figure out the preferred way to work with HttpClient, et al.

---

According to [Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html):

```
// The underlying HTTP connection is still held by the response object
// to allow the response content to be streamed directly from the network socket.
// In order to ensure correct deallocation of system resources
// the user MUST call CloseableHttpResponse#close() from a finally clause.
```

In addition, the relationships go as follows:

> `HttpClient` (interface)
>
> > implemented by:
> >
> > > `CloseableHttpClient` - ThreadSafe.
> > >
> > > `DefaultHttpClient` - ThreadSafe BUT [deprecated](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html), use `HttpClientBuilder` instead.
>
> `HttpClientBuilder` - NOT ThreadSafe, BUT creates ThreadSafe `CloseableHttpClient`.
>
> > - Use to create CUSTOM `CloseableHttpClient`.
>
> `HttpClients` - NOT ThreadSafe, BUT creates ThreadSafe `CloseableHttpClient`.
>
> > - Use to create DEFAULT or MINIMAL `CloseableHttpClient`.

The preferred way according to Apache:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

[The example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java) they give does `httpclient.close()` in the `finally` clause, and also makes use of `ResponseHandler` as well.

---

As an alternative, the way mkyong does it is a bit interesting, as well:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

He doesn't show a `client.close()` call but I would think it is necessary, since `client` is still an instance of `CloseableHttpClient`.

Comment: ```HttpClientBuilder.create().build();``` is what ``HttpClients.createDefault();`` uses under the hood, so there shouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers don't seem to address why `close()` is really necessary? * 2

#### Doubt on the answer "HttpClient resource deallocation".

It is mentioned in old 3.x httpcomponents [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html), which is long back and has a lot difference from 4.x HC. Besides the explanation is so brief that doesn't say what this underlying resource is.

I did some research on 4.5.2 release source code, found the implementations of `CloseableHttpClient:close()` basically only closes its connection manager.

(FYI) That's why when you use a shared `PoolingClientConnectionManager` and call client `close()`, exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down` will occur. To avoid, `setConnectionManagerShared` works.

#### I prefer *not* do `CloseableHttpClient:close()` after every single request

I used to create a new http client instance when doing request and finally close it. In this case, it'd better not to call `close()`. Since, if connection manager doesn't have "shared" flag, it'll be shutdown, which is too expensive for a single request.

In fact, I also found in library [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http), a Clojure wrapper over Apache HC 4.5, doesn't call `close()` at all. See func `request` in file [core.clj](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/core.clj)

Comment: Could you clarify why it's better than use setConnectionManagerShared and call close() after every request?

Answer (score 10):

`HttpClient` is not a class, it is an interface. You cannot use it for development in the way you mean.

What you want is a class that implements the `HttpClient` interface, and that is `CloseableHttpClient`.

Answer (score 8):

In the next major version of the library `HttpClient` interface is going to extend `Closeable`. Until then it is recommended to use `CloseableHttpClient` if compatibility with earlier 4.x versions (4.0, 4.1 and 4.2) is not required.

Comment: History says that you were wrong, because here we are in v5.1 and HttpClient still does not extend Closeable https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/classic/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 2):

`CloseableHttpClient` is the base class of the httpclient library, the one all implementations use. Other subclasses are for the most part deprecated.

The `HttpClient` is an interface for this class and other classes.

You should then use the `CloseableHttpClient` in your code, and create it using the `HttpClientBuilder`. If you need to wrap the client to add specific behaviour you should use request and response interceptors instead of wrapping with the `HttpClient`.

This answer was given in the context of httpclient-4.3.

Answer (score 1):

**Jon skeet said:**

The documentation seems pretty clear to me: "Base implementation of HttpClient that also implements Closeable" - HttpClient is an interface; CloseableHttpClient is an abstract class, but because it implements AutoCloseable you can use it in a try-with-resources statement.

**But then Jules asked:**

@JonSkeet That much is clear, but how important is it to close HttpClient instances? If it's important, why is the close() method not part of the basic interface?

**Answer for Jules**

> close need not be part of basic interface since underlying connection
>   is released back to the connection manager automatically after every execute

To accommodate the  try-with-resources statement. It is mandatory to implement Closeable. Hence included it in **CloseableHttpClient**.

Note:

close method in AbstractHttpClient which is extending CloseableHttpClient is deprecated, I was not able to find the source code for that.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to answer "how important is it to close HttpClient instances?"

Comment: This answer implies that you don't have to close HttpClient instances at all, which in turn implies that CloseableHttpClient was simply a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the *Closeables* like this

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/*****";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
try (final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
     final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
    final String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Here you create a CloseableHttpClient instance for every single request, isn't it expensive?