# What is the difference between using HTTPClientBuilder.create().build() vs HTTPClient.custom().build()

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to create the HTTPClient for building a framework using Apache HTTPClient in Java for REST webservices.

Here I found that we can create the client using the below two ways. I want to know the difference between them.

1.HTTPCLientBuilder.create().build()

2.HTTPClients.custom().build()

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on SO, just a bit hidden. Reposting euphoria99's answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574478/what-is-the-difference-between-closeablehttpclient-and-httpclient-in-apache-http):

```
HttpClient (interface)

implemented by:

CloseableHttpClient - ThreadSafe.

DefaultHttpClient - ThreadSafe BUT deprecated, use HttpClientBuilder instead.
HttpClientBuilder - NOT ThreadSafe, BUT creates ThreadSafe CloseableHttpClient.

Use to create CUSTOM CloseableHttpClient.
HttpClients - NOT ThreadSafe, BUT creates ThreadSafe CloseableHttpClient.

Use to create DEFAULT or MINIMAL CloseableHttpClient.
```

So when you write `.custom()` and then don't `set` any custom things, there is, aparently, no differnce

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of `HttpClients` you will see:

```
/**
 * Creates builder object for construction of custom
 * {@link CloseableHttpClient} instances.
 */
public static HttpClientBuilder custom() {
    return HttpClientBuilder.create();
}
```

So, to answer the question, the only difference is one extra call in the stack as one uses the other.

Talking in general:

- `HttpClients` has predetermined "configurations" for creating `HttpClient` instances.
- `HttpClientBuilder` is for building new `HttpClient` instances that you can customize during the building process and it is used by `HttpClients` in some of its methods.