# Why do HTTP connections in a pool become stale? And are there guidelines on how can I calculate an eviction policy?

Tags: java, http, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm a beginner to request/response service programming using apache HTTP clients and am trying to understand how a client with a connection pool to a server might have some connections go stale in that pool.

Here's what I currently understand:

- stale connections are a result of the server disconnecting the connection but the client not knowing
- trying to use a stale connection on a request could result in `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException`
- connection pools should have an eviction policy to clean up stale connections and remake new ones, however there is a tradeoff for performance because new connections are expensive to make

I currently have a service that is getting called about 20 req/second and I get `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException` (presumably due to stale connections) about 15 times an hour. How can I calculate my eviction policy?

I'm using a threadpool of 10 threads. Current eviction policy is to scan the pool every 5 seconds and remove threads that are idle for 30 seconds or more.

I'm interested in if there is a rough estimation process for structuring my eviction policy?

Comment: Trying to use a stale connection *will fail.* There is no 'tradeoff for performance', as there is no correct behaviour with a stale connection. Only you know how long your server will hold a kept-alive HTTP connection, so only you can determine the correct idle timeout. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901789/2834978) helps a bit. Your eviction policy might be too long.