# When NOT to use HTTP Connection Pooling?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, resttemplate, httpconnection, spring-webclient

In my Java application, I am using a single object of *RestTemplate* for calling one HTTP endpoint. The resttemplate is a default one (instantiated by `new RestTemplate()` at the time of application start up) and so it doesn't has any connection pooling. Since the frequency of its usage is very less (about 50 calls per day), I am of the opinion that connection pooling should not be used as it will add to the overhead. Am I correct in my assumption?

Is there any standard use-case where HTTP connection-pooling should not be used?

Comment: Put it another way, it probably won't *help.* 50 calls/day is 2.0833/hour, or about every 30 minutes, and any sensible server is going to close an idle connection long before 30 minutes.

Comment: You will get the same overhead with or without it since new connections must be established anyway. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901789/2834978) has some info on that.