# Http 1.1 connection pooling vs Websockets

Tags: websocket, connection-pooling, http-1.1

Generally people compared Websockets and http long polling.

But in connection pooling using http 1.1 (which browser does or we do from application server to db server ) , persistent connection is made and all http requests made through same connection (similar concepts of Websockets)

Only difference is Websockets is bidirectional but http 1.1 connection will be request/response based.

Any other difference?

Comment: Depends on the client language I guess, on java [connections are reusable rather than persistant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901789/2834978)

Comment: this is new for me. what is difference of reusing & persisting ? I mean how can we reuse a connection, it means the connection was not closed & remain open/persistent ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection here it means both are same and not different