# How can I migrate call to HttpMethodBase.setConnectionCloseForced(true) from commons-httpclient 3.x to httpcomponents-client 4.x?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-commons-httpclient

I have some code that I need to migrate from commons-httpclient 3.x to httpcomponents-client 4.x (or newer). In some error handling code, there are calls to `setConnectionCloseForced(true)` on subclasses of `HttpMethodBase`, such as `GetMethod` or `PostMethod`. What would be the equivalent in httpcomponents-client 4.x?

```java
HttpMethodBase httpMethod = /* some value */;
try {
    // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
} finally {
    // how to convert this?
    httpMethod.setConnectionCloseForced(true);
}
```

Comment: IIRC you need to do it at the "[type]HTTPMethod" something like: `getMethod.releaseConnection();`

Comment: This thread may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574478/what-is-the-difference-between-closeablehttpclient-and-httpclient-in-apache-http